# C++ Win32 "Resource Manager" for Editors

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to make a "Resource Manager" class of some sorts, kinda like those lists/trees you see in editors.

So it should be able to create folders, subfolders, and add files and allow reorganizing etc

At first I tried to make a custom class using **static** controls, but it was a pain to handle everything since it seems static controls aren't really supposed to be changing.
Thinking I was doing it wrong, I looked for an alternative and decided to use the **listbox** control.

This time it was much easier handling the messages and inserts/removes/reorders, etc.

But then I started to add the "fancy" stuff such as giving a line a specific icon to expand that folder, using a static icon control, but when I select a line in the listbox, it draws over the static control (icon).

So my question is, how am I supposed to do this?
Am I trying to reinvent the wheel or something, or is there something else ready to use in the Win32 API?
(I don't plan on using 3rd party libraries, this is for educational purposes, so I'd like to do using only C++ and the Win32 API)

What I want to do is something like this:

[image]

Just point me to the right direction please!

Comment: Voila - Common Controls *TreeView*; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760017(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yup, with the "Explorer" visual style.  The screenshot is actually WPF.

Comment: It's best to familiarize yourself with all the common controls in the Win32 API before trying to build things using static controls.